# Explaining a simple observation on Terry Tao's blog about the Wiener process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Quoting [Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/254a-notes-3b-brownian-motion-and-dyson-brownian-motion/):

> A simple but fundamental observation is that $n$-dimensional Brownian
>   motion is rotation-invariant: more precisely, if $(X_t)_{t \in
>  [0,+\infty)}$ is an $n$-dimensional Wiener process with initial
>   position $0$, and $U \in O(n)$ is any orthogonal transformation on
>   ${\bf R}^n$, then $(UX_t)_{t \in [0,+\infty)}$ is another Wiener
>   process with initial position $0$, and thus has the same distribution:
>
> $(UX_t)_{t \in [0,+\infty)} \equiv (X_t)_{t \in [0,+\infty)}$.
>
> This is ultimately because the $n$-dimensional normal distributions $N(0,\sigma^2 I)_{{\bf R}^n}$ are manifestly rotation-invariant (see Exercise 10 of Notes 1).

I do not have the solution to Exercise 10 and I do not see directly how it's related. Could someone clarify in more detail how this explains that Brownian motion is rotation-invariant? (To show that all the conditions don't change).

Comment: I think he is stating a fact that if the pdf of a distribution only depends on the quadratic form $\mathbf{x}^T \sigma^2I \mathbf{x}$ (a special case of those elliptical distribution), then it will be rotational invariant about the mean. For example, a standard bivariate normal joint pdf has a circular contour, any rotation transformation will preserve the same structure. (and thus remain independent)

Comment: @BGM: Okay, how does that preserve the properties of the Wiener process in particular?

Comment: @user322202 Continuity will not be harmed by rotation. Gaussianity will not be harmed either. You can check the mean and the covariance functions yourself to see if they will remain invariant.

Comment: @Calculon I understand that and it seems reasonable to me, but I would like to see a rigorous proof if possible.

Comment: $e^{-x^2-y^2}=e^{-r^2}$. All the proof you need.

Comment: @A.S. Where does that equation come from? Care to give me another hint?

Comment: LHS is just a joint pdf of two i.i.d standard normals (upto 2 linear factors). $x^2+y^2=r^2$ is just Pythagorean theorem (think polar coordinates).

Comment: @A.S. I was thinking that in two dimensions, I would multiply with an orthogonal matrix {{cos (theta), -sin (theta)}, {sin (theta), cos (theta)}} {x, y} which equals (x cos(theta)-y sin(theta), y cos(theta)+x sin(theta)). How do I show that this result is an equivalent Wiener process?

Comment: On second thought Levy's characterization of BM is perfect for this problem.

Comment: If the joint pdf depends on $r$ only (and not on $\theta$), then it doesn't change under rotations (shifts of $\theta$).

Comment: @A.S. But the result that I'm getting there seems to be depending on theta, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Let $W_t$ be an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion. Then, we of course know that $t \mapsto W_t(\omega)$ is continuous everywhere for every $\omega$ in a full measure set. $W_0 = 0$ a.s. and $[W^i,W^j]_t = \delta_{ij}t$ where $W^i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of $W$ and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. Finally, $(W^i_t)_t$ is a martingale for every $i=1,\ldots,n$.

Define $X_t(\omega) = RW_t(\omega)$ for every $t$ and $\omega$ where $R$ is a rotation matrix. For every $\omega$ such that $t \mapsto W_t(\omega)$ is continuous, $t \mapsto RW_t(\omega)$ is continuous as well. $X_0 = 0$ a.s. also.

Let $X^j$ denote the $j^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of the process $X$. Then, $X^j_t = R^jW_t$ where $R_j$ is the $j^{\text{th}}$ row of $R$. For $s \leq t$,
$$E[X^j_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = E[R^jW_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = R^jE[W_t \mid \mathcal{F}_s] = R^jW_s =: X^j_s$$
So $X$ is a martingale itself.

Let $R^i_k$ denote the row $i$, column $k$ element of $R$.

$$[X^i,X^j]_t = [R^iW,R^jW]_t = [\sum_{k=1}^nR^i_kW^k,\sum_{k=1}^nR^j_kW^k]_t = t\sum_{k=1}^nR^i_kR^j_k$$

Since $R$ is a rotation matrix, $R^{\top}R = I$. Hence $\sum_{k=1}^nR^i_kR^j_k =  \delta_{ij}$.

Then, by Levy's characterization we know $X$ must be BM.

Comment: Hi thanks, but what is $\mathcal{F}_s$?

Comment: @user322202 it is some filtration with respect to which $W$ is BM.